# Laplace transform - specifc formula

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, laplace-transform

My question is: how to obtain

$$
\frac{1}{x + y + 2\lambda} = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int^\infty_{-\infty} \left(\frac{1}{x + \lambda + i\mu}\right)\left(\frac{1}{y + \lambda - i\mu}\right) \,\mathrm d\mu \, ?
$$

for $x, y, \lambda > 0$. This is supposed to be a case of Laplace transform but I don't really see how to show the equality.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha tells me the RHS is zero. I reached the same conclusion integrating via partial fractions. Regardless of whether I try integrating with respect to $\mu$ or $\lambda$. Just to be sure, are you sure you wrote it correctly?

Comment: Yes, this comes from the paper (p. 120):

http://math.caltech.edu/SimonPapers/30.pdf

Comment: $$\frac 1 {2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty
 \frac {d \mu} {(x + \lambda + i \mu) (y + \lambda - i \mu)} =
i \operatorname{Res}_{\mu = i(x + \lambda)}
 \frac 1 {(x + \lambda + i \mu) (y + \lambda - i \mu)}.$$
The other pole is in the lower half-plane.